# Правильное приведение от структуры к структуре в фабрике

Tags: golang, интерфейс, struct

Не хочу плодить однотипный код по созданию объектов структур, но никак не могу найти правильный рабочий подход к реализации на Go:

```
type DecodeFrame struct {
    name    string
    decData map[string]string
}

type Frame struct {
    header  byte
    command [2]byte
    length  int
    rawData []byte
    CRC     byte
    DecodeFrame
}
type Decoder interface {
    decodeData()
}

type FrameCanBusState Frame


func (f *FrameCanBusState) decodeData() {
//specific realisation}

type FrameCommands Frame

func (f *FrameCommands) decodeData() {
// specific realisation}

func newFrame(rawFrameBytes []byte) *Frame {
    frame := new(Frame)
    length := rawFrameBytes[2]
    rawData := rawFrameBytes[3 : len(rawFrameBytes)-1]

    frame.header = Header[0]
    frame.command = [2]byte{rawFrameBytes[1], rawFrameBytes[0]}
    frame.length = int(length)
    frame.rawData = rawData
    frame.CRC = rawFrameBytes[len(rawFrameBytes)-1]
    frame.decData = make(map[string]string)
    return frame
}
func factoryDecoders(rawFrame *Frame) (Decoder, error) {
    switch {
    // this place, i don`t know how implement
    case: fr := rawFrame.(FrameStateFlags) // error 
    case: fr := rawFrame.(FrameCommands) // error
    }
 }



func main() {
     rawBytes := // parse
     rawFrame := newFrame(rawBytes)
     decoder := factoryDecoders(rawFrame)
     decoder.decodeData()
}
```

Может, я что то не так пишу. Или что-то не понимаю, прошу не бить а объяснить как правильно кастовать в данном случае чтобы следовать еще и DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде возникает ошибка из-за того, что вы пытаетесь явно привести объект типа `*Frame` к типу `FrameStateFlags` или FrameCommands, что невозможно, так как эти типы объявлены как алиасы для типа Frame.

Вам нужно использовать конструкцию `type assertion`, чтобы убедиться в том, что объект принадлежит нужному вам типу:

```
if fr, ok := rawFrame.(*FrameStateFlags); ok {
    // объект типа *FrameStateFlags
} else if fr, ok := rawFrame.(*FrameCommands); ok {
    // объект типа *FrameCommands
} else {
    // объект не типа *FrameStateFlags и не типа *FrameCommands
}
```

Также стоит отметить, что ваш код не совсем следует принципу "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY). В частности, у вас повторяется код инициализации полей структуры `Frame`, который выполняется в функции `newFrame`. Вы можете сделать эту функцию фабричной и использовать ее для создания экземпляров разных типов `Frame`, например:

```
type FrameType int

const (
    FrameTypeStateFlags FrameType = iota
    FrameTypeCommands
    // другие типы фреймов
)

func NewFrame(frameType FrameType, rawFrameBytes []byte) *Frame {
    frame := new(Frame)
    length := rawFrameBytes[2]
    rawData := rawFrameBytes[3 : len(rawFrameBytes)-1]

    frame.header = Header[0]
    frame.command = [2]byte{rawFrameBytes[1], rawFrameBytes[0]}
    frame.length = int(length)
    frame.rawData = rawData
    frame.CRC = rawFrameBytes[len(rawFrameBytes)-1]
    frame.decData = make(map[string]string)

    switch frameType {
    case FrameTypeStateFlags:
        frame.DecodeFrame = &FrameStateFlags{}
    case FrameTypeCommands:
        frame.DecodeFrame = &FrameCommands{}
    // другие типы фреймов
    }

    return frame
}
```

Теперь вы можете использовать эту функцию для создания экземпляров разных типов `Frame`:

```
rawFrameBytes := // parse

rawFrame := NewFrame(FrameTypeStateFlags, rawFrameBytes)
decoder := rawFrame.DecodeFrame.(Decoder)
decoder.decodeData()

rawFrame = NewFrame(FrameTypeCommands, rawFrameBytes)
decoder = rawFrame.DecodeFrame.(Decoder)
decoder.decodeData()
```

Таким образом, вы не повторяете код инициализации общих полей структуры `Frame` и можете создавать экземпляры разных типов `Frame`, не писая отдельный код для каждого типа.